CXF Camel - WS-Security ResourceResolverException with concurrent requests
We have an integration solution running as Camel+CXF exposing SOAP services with WS-Security (signed request/response). The app is bundled as a Spring app in JBoss (Wildfly + JKD11)
The service (client) is defined:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-2.1.0.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">

    <!-- Request: redacted  Response: redacted -->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="redactedEntitiyService" 
                     address="${cxf.outbound.redacted.address}" 
                     serviceClass="service.redacted.Entitiyservice.EntitiyServicePortType" 
                     bindingId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"> 
        <cxf:features>
        </cxf:features>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPInInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/> 
            <ref bean="WSSecurityredactedResponseInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="wsaHeaderInInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="WSSecurityredactedRequestInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <bean id="wsaHeaderInInterceptor" class="routes.interceptor.HeaderInterceptor" />

    <bean id="WSSecurityredactedRequestInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                <entry key="user" value="somekey"/>             <!-- server key alias -->
                <entry key="timeToLive" value="60"/>
                <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="appKeystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="routes.wssecurity.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
                <entry key="signatureParts"
                       value="{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action;{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}MessageID;{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}To"/>
                <entry key="signatureDigestAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="WSSecurityredactedResponseInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                <entry key="user" value="redactedkey"/>             <!-- server key alias -->
                <entry key="timeToLive" value="60"/>
                <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="appKeystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="routes.wssecurity.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
                <entry key="signatureDigestAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


After time we noticed exceptions validating the response signature
Original Exception was javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: org.apache.xml.security.utils.res
olver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID Id-8cQDFTql5kj71pwUOwvpbw22
        at deployment.APP.war//org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:399)
        at deployment.APP.war//org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:232)
        at deployment.APP.war//org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:340)
        at deployment.APP.war//org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:314)
        ... 11 more
...
        ... 18 more
[2024-04-19 14:21:03,220  ] ERROR  CamelLogger: Unexpected exception org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID Id-8cQDFTql5kj71pwUOwvpbw22


The most strange was that the element Id was not present in the response message at all. We found the mentioned element ID in completely different response message (which was executing concurrently with the failed one).
Used versions:

JDK (corretto) 11
wss4j-ws-security:2.2.2
cxf:3.3.0
spring:5.0.7.RELEASE
camel:2.19.5
Wildfly-11


maybe related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8077 .. investigating
